# Change list element class on smoothscroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the class of a list < li> element to class="active" when I scroll to it.

```
function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#menu').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#menu ul li').removeClass("active"); //added to remove active class from all a elements
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

here is my menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" id="header" role="navigation" data-offset-top="100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Description Header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">More links</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">And one to grow on</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if I'm modifying the list element correctly or not. The smooth scrolling works fine, but the class won't change.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you applying it in the `onScroll` if you want it to happen on a click?

Comment: It's a single page template. The click will scroll to it, and when it is scrolled to I want it to change to active.

Comment: Where is `onScroll` being called? Can we see a live demo?

Comment: at the bottom of the page in the javascript. it's a local file so i cant link unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
$("li").click(function(){
 $(".active").removeClass(".actvie");
 $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I'd like to try and use the onscroll event so it changes when it's scrolled to as well.

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: Not quite. I want to do it when i scroll